# Unable to create using button on VOB

Tags: custom-button, button

I have created a button called create VOB button which generates a pdf version. For a particular user, i am getting an error message but it works for other users. Unable to find the cause.

[image]

[image]

I am unable to find the reason why this particular user is not able to generate pfd while others are?

Comment: Check its profile/permission set/license

Comment: This happens most frequently when a profile as read access on a lookup field, but not on the object that field looks up to.